# Handling "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" in Java

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to perform File Attachment operation through my java code. But it is returning me "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" in my Console output. Can you please help me with this. Rest nothing is wrong in my code.

Following is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://watsonexp-stg.corp.adobe.com/watson/api/bug/addAttachmentAPI.jsp");

            //to make a multipart POST request
             MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, null, Charset.forName(HTTP.UTF_8));
             multipartEntity.addPart("appGUID", new StringBody("e2513b90-f327-4cc0-8c07-2d79a1b6eddd"));
             multipartEntity.addPart("userId", new StringBody("karansha"));
             multipartEntity.addPart("password", new StringBody("RGVsbCUxMDA="));
             multipartEntity.addPart("bugId", new StringBody("3402114"));

             multipartEntity.addPart("fileDescription", new StringBody("trying to attach a file"));
             multipartEntity.addPart("external", new StringBody("false"));
             multipartEntity.addPart("Filedata", new FileBody(new File("C:/Users/karansha/Desktop/test.jpg")));

             httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);

             HttpResponse res= httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            //following lines will print out the respose from the server on attempting to upload a file.

             HttpEntity httpEntity = res.getEntity();
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpEntity.getContent()));
             String  line = "";
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                 System.out.println(line);
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post the complete stack-trace

Comment: Do you mind also showing your `import` lines as well

Comment: @SonuKrishan It is not clear which line of the above code is throwing the exception. Please post the complete stack trace like Apurv asked.

Comment: *"Rest nothing is wrong in my code."*  What?  That sentence makes no sense to me.

Comment: Most likely you have not configured your classpath correctly but you will have to provide more details to get more complete answers.

Comment: The problem is in rest of the code.

Comment: import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
 
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
 
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;

Comment: Post the entire stacktrace please

Comment: First google hit for `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`: http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html Please check everything mentioned in this blog post and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that there is some class that you have at compile time that is somehow missing at runtime.  Take note of your class path during compile and compare it to your runtime environment.  That should help you find your missing class.